# Best statistical test to observe if there is a statistical difference between three categories using trial data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I have created sixteen trials to observe if there is a relationship between two coral species (if they are found near each other often). For one example, I have 12 occurrences where there is a positive relationship between the two, 3 occurrences where there is no significant relationship found, and 1 occurrence where there is a negative relationship between the two. What statistical test should I use to find if there is a statistical difference between the three relationship types?

Comment: What did you do in your 16 observations to determine that the relationships are positive and negative?

Comment: If the actual mean ratio that a coral species took up of a certain space around another coral species was smaller or greater than a null distribution formed from random sampling of the pairing then it had a negative or positive relationship.